# Tree like structure

Tags: tikz-trees

Can anyone help me to get this kind of structure in latex:

[image]

I just don't know even where to start..

Thank you

Comment: The tag that you used is a good place to start. Please show that you have made some effort before asking others to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options for this, you can try

- [`tikz`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en)
- [`forest`](https://ctan.org/pkg/forest?lang=en)
- [`qtree`](https://ctan.org/pkg/qtree?lang=en)
- [`tikz-qtree`](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/tikz-qtree.html#Docs)

Here's an example using `tikz-qtree`

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
  \Tree [.S [.DP$\downarrow$ \edge[dashed];  [.DP Uruguay ] ] 
             [.VP [.V wins ] [.DP$\downarrow$ ] ] ]
  %
  \begin{scope}[shift = {(5cm, 0cm)}]
  \Tree [.S [.DP Uruguay ]  
            [.VP [.V wins ] [.DP$\downarrow$ ] ] ]
  \end{scope}
  %
  \draw[->, yshift = -1.5cm] (2, 0) -- (3, 0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]